# A short guide explaining "How mathematicians talk" and common mathematical notations

Tags: reference-request, notation

Is there an introductary text/note, say like 5-15 pages that specifially focuses on explaining "How mathematicians talk", e.g. formulations like

"Let A be a set. $\forall x \in A, \exists y \in B$"
or 
"We then say that $f$ has an inverse function $f^{-1}: X \rightarrow Y$, that maps a unique point in .." or "f is everywhere $0$, hence $f \equiv 0$.

There is someone with background in economy, having completed 2-3 mathematical courses of type calculus and optimization, that is seeking such an introductary text. The background is that one of her professors commonly uses such language as above, and not being used to this way of writing, she has trouble following him.

So I am seeking a short simple-worded guide into the language of mathematics and mathematical notation. The text should preferably cover notations like $\forall, \exists, \subseteq, A \rightarrow B, x \mapsto y$, !. The text should preferably be easily accessible and available for free online.

Comment: A lot of "first course in real analysis" type books start with a discussion of basic (naive) set theory and mathematical logic.  The chapter or two on these topics is likely to be more than 5-15 pages in most of these books but perhaps she could pick up one and try it.  One example off the top of my head is Stephen Lay's *Analysis with an Introduction to Proof*.  The first chapter is on logic and the second chapter is on naive set theory.

Comment: It's not short, but Wells's *Handbook of Mathematical Discourse* describes many phrases used in mathematical English. Here is a PDF of it: http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Bernard.Ycart/writing/hyperhbk.pdf It's more focused on words and phrases than notation - it's hard to separate questions of notation from understanding the mathematical concepts themselves.

Answer (score 3):

You're unlikely to find a "universal" reference that covers all notation, but you'd already get far by knowing the basic notations from set theory. Check out [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/0809/CompTheory/comt09.pdf) for example. There is also [this page](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.htm), which covers a lot of common symbols from various mathematical areas.

Of course, these references only give you defintions for what these things mean. To really get a feel for "how mathematicians talk," how they think, and how they use these symbols, experience is probably the best teacher.